# Beamer : Page number without total number of pages

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I'm using beamer (Darmstadt theme and seahorse color) and I would like to print the page number in the format of the lone current page number rather than 'current page number / total number of pages'; i.e., 1, 2,... rather than 1/18, 2/18.. because the end of my beamer is actually a FAQ that may not be presented if not required and also because in my own experience, part of the audience loses their patience when they see the speech is not getting to its close.

I currently use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

which gives me current page/total page, is there such a simple way to only get page number ?
Thank you for the help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that there are switches somewhere in beamer for doing this, but here is one way of doing it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1ex]{author in head/foot}
      \rlap{\textit{\insertshorttitle}}\hfill\insertauthor\hfill\llap{\insertframenumber}%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

  \title{A great talk}
  \author{The speaker}

  \begin{frame}{A nice frame}
    Some interesting stuff!
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]