# How to Exclude Total Slide Number from Beamer Slide

Tags: beamer, numbering, page-numbering

Here is a MWE for my Beamer slides:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[Name of Presentation Slides]{Name}
\author[Author A and Author B]{Author A and Author B}
\date[September 20, 2017]{September 20, 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Slide}
\textbf{Letters}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to keep the same format in the bottom bar, but simply exclude the slide total, so that only the current slide is displayed.

I tried the following solutions from these questions ([Beamer : Page number without total number of pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210525/beamer-page-number-without-total-number-of-pages?rq=1)  and   [Beamer frame number without total](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333587/beamer-frame-number-without-total), but they never quite worked right, always modifying the other parts of the bottom bar in some way.

1.

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1ex]{author in head/foot}
      \rlap{\textit{\insertshorttitle}}\hfill\insertauthor\hfill\llap{\insertframenumber}%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

2.

```
\setbeamertemplate {footline}{\quad\hfill\insertframenumber\strut\quad}
```

3.

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{% 
  \hfill% 
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}% 
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}% 
  \insertframenumber%
  %\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
  \kern1em\vskip2pt% 
}
```

What is to be done in my instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Madrid theme uses the footline from the infolines outer theme, you can redefine it like this:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[Name of Presentation Slides]{Name}
\author[Author A and Author B]{Author A and Author B}
\date[September 20, 2017]{September 20, 2017}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{}%
%     / \inserttotalframenumber
    \hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Slide}
\textbf{Letters}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Starting with beamer v. 3.49 the new beamer template `page number in head/foot` simplifies this to:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It almost works. I get this error: `Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \ifblank`. If I delete `\ifblank` from the code, it works, but places `( )` after the author name(s).

Comment: @bill999 Do you get this error with exactly the code from my answer? How do you compile? pdflatex or something else? Which tex distribution do you have? I tried with pdflatex from texlive2017 and it works without any errors.

Comment: Yes, exactly the code from the answer. I have a Mac and am using TeXShop version 3.87.

Comment: @bill999 Can you share the .log file?

Comment: I tried to copy and paste the output of the log file, but the character limit was exceeded. Is there a way to attach the file? Or is one part of the log file more relevant than another?

Comment: If you are comfortable to put the log file on an external service https://pastebin.com/ could help. Other then that, I would be interested in the start of the log file (this should tell which tex distribution you use), the middle part to see which package versions you have and the end around where the error occurs.

Comment: See if this works: https://pastebin.com/fLibbftt

Comment: @bill999 This is the complete log file you get? Looks truncated - it does not include the error message from your first comment. Maybe updating your tex distribution could help.

Comment: Yes, I double-checked, and that is the complete log file. I don't know why the error message isn't contained in it.

Comment: I ended up deleting `\ifblank`. The problem with the `( )` after the author names was resolved by deleting `{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}`. So we are good!